# Can't create new folder in my video folder or find the files

Tags: windows-7

I can't create a folder in the video folder or see the files I saved on a system running Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit. I can see the files in the root location of the folder by going to the folder from My Computer. I can also create and find files when I go to the folder:

> My Computer > C > Users > User > Documents > Downloads > Video

My video folder location is C:\Users\User\Documents\Downloads\Video.

I actually didn't see the New folder option while trying to create a folder. But if I go to the Video folder and "open folder location" from the main folder I am able to create folders and can find my files.

I tried:

- deleting the video folder from the download folder
- creating a new folder in the the same location and stored files

I can see the files in both locations but when I rename the folder to "Video" I can't see files or get the option to create "New Folder".

[image: Please See the Both the Folders Print Scr]

[image: Folders after renaming]

Comment: You have not told what error you getting at the time of creating the `new folder`.

Comment: Please add the screen shot of the `menu` when you not getting the option of `create new folder` with the location.

Comment: Avirk, As I mentioned If i delete the video folder and creates a new folder in the name of Video1 then it shows all files and options. As I renames the folder to Video I can't see the files not gets the New Folder Create option.

Comment: Though it is not a problem. As i can see the files and can create folder by renaming the Folder VIDEO to VIDEO1. But as being a System admin i can't stop thinking that how this can be possible. A Folder works well till renaming to VIDEO, as it is renamed it stops showing files and stop showing New Folder Creating option.

Comment: As I can see they both are different locations. But if you getting this problem try to repair the windows at least once or try to restore first.

Comment: Avirk, The left Folder is the one showing problem and the right one is when I right click the left one and choose OPEN FOLDER LOCATION i.e the main location of the folder. I have added a new PrntSc after renaming the folder. You can see they both are same.

Comment: After uninstalling and Reinstalling the Internet Download Manager the Problem got solved..Thanks all for your valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling and Reinstalling the Internet Download Manager the Problem Resolved..Thanks all for your valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Please do a check of the permissions, as shown in the image below:

[image: Security settings]

---

### EDIT

I think this might solve your trouble:

- Open the **Group Policy Management** Console. Right-click the **Group Policy** object (GPO) that should contain the new preference item, and then click Edit.
- In the console tree under *User Configuration*, expand the Preferences folder, and then expand the **Control Panel** Settings folder.
- Right-click the **Folder Options** node, point to New, and select **Folder Options** (Windows Vista and later).
- In the New Folder Options Properties dialog box, enter folder options settings for Group Policy to configure. (For more information, see Enable and Disable Settings in a Preference Item.)
- Click the Common tab, configure any options, and then type your comments in the Description box. (For more information, see *Configure Common Options*.)
- Click **OK**. The new preference item appears in the details pane.

[As read on Microsoft technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771379.aspx)

*P.S.*: Group Policy Manager: Type gpedit.msc in "Run..." window.

Comment: Please elaborate it if you want to help him.

Comment: hjpotter I am the owner of the folder. As I mentioned being a System Admin I tried all the process that can be followed. But I Am facing this problem 1st time and never seen such type of problem.

Comment: @tiki Please check the edited answer and inform. :)

Comment: Sorry to say potter but I don't have the Group Policy Management.